# Modificar mi filtro para mostrar los datos en la vista

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo un problema con un filtro que he creado gracias a la comunidad de stackoverflow pero no termina de trabajar correctamente, culpa mia por supuesto.

Este problema lo voy a dividir en 2 partes, ya que primero, necesito traer los datos correctos al datepicker y segundo necesito filtrar bien los datos que recibe el metodo del controlador para guardar los datos. Dicho esto voy a intentar explicarlo lo mejor posible.

Yo tengo este datepicker, en el cual podeis ver que filtro por un parametro que en este caso es acept:

```
<script>
  // here receive the json array from PHP to JS
  var daysData = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;
  var newA = [];
for( j of daysData){
  let start = moment(j["start"]);
  let end   = moment(j["end"]);

  for (let m = moment(start); m.diff(end, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
    newA[m.format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = j;
  }
}

$('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({

    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
      var valid = false ; // default css class
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
         if(newA[d].acept == 1){
            valid =  true;
        }
      }
      return valid;
    },
   isCustomDate: function(date) {

      var daySettings = 'day_green';
      let d =  date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");
      if(typeof newA[d] !== 'undefined'){
       daySettings = 'day_red';
       if(newA[d].acept == 0){
        daySettings = 'day_orange';
       }
      }
      return daySettings;
    },

});
</script>
```

Pero tengo otra variable en el json que me viene del controlador que es area_id, que me marca el area de los usuarios que solicitan las vacaciones. Con lo cual lo que me gustaria es que aparte de pintar los colores que ya tengo codificados, solo me muestre los datos correspondientes al area, del usuario que intenta solicitar vacaciones, ejemplo: departamento de informatica, con 2 personas, solo esas dos personas podrian ver las vacaciones de ellos dos.

Edito: parte del controlador solucionado gracias a Javier en los comentarios.

```
        //Filtro de inserción en bd.
        //if($vacation != $guardadas){
            if($vacation->date_from != $guardadas[0]->date_from and $vacation->date_to != $guardadas[0]->date_to || $vacation->area_id != $guardadas[0]->area_id){

           $vacation->save();

            $data = request()->all();

           return back()->with('success','Vacaciones Solicitadas correctamente');

        }else{
            return back()->with('error','Fechas no disponibles');
        }

        return back();
```

Antes de nada muchas gracias por su ayuda y atención.

Saludos.

Comment: Esta línea sobra: $guardadas = new Vacation();. Además, no veo porque añades tantas condiciones sobre las fechas. Con la primera que tienes ya cubres el resto. Otra cosa: más abajo estás comparando las fechas directamente y eso puede ser un problema dependiendo de si las tienes guardadas como datetime. No termino de entender si tu problema está a la hora de obtener las vacaciones guardadas o al guardar las nuevas

Comment: Hola Javier, anteriormente habia preguntado para filtrar por todos los intervalos de fechas, ya que si no hago esas condiciones si selecciono determinados dias no me los filtra correctamente, en este caso, las condiciones estan correctas, lo que necesitaria seria cambiar el IF, podria ponerte los outputs de los distintos objetos, en principio la comparacion de fechas es correcta, necesito, cambiar primero el filtro del datepicker para visualizar correctamente las fechas que stan bloqueadas segun el area, y ya despues revisaria ese filtro ya que tndria que hacer algo parecido. Disculpa el texto

Comment: En resumen, del metodo que hace el save, solo necesitaria revisar el condicional de || $vacation->area_id != $guardadas[0]->area_id). Saludos y gracias por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: Tienes un and y un or en ese if sin separar por paréntesis, lo cual no tiene sentido. No sé si con eso ya tienes suficiente: if (($vacation->date_from != $guardadas[0]->date_from and $vacation->date_to != $guardadas[0]->date_to) || $vacation->area_id != $guardadas[0]->area_id) {

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier, voy a testearlo ahora, edito el post. Ahora solo me falta retocar el js para que solo me pinte las fechas segun el area_id :)